# Get-Process "Username" returning my own username when no user is logged in on a remote machine

Tags: powershell

I'm using Get-Process to query logged on users of remote machines. It works really well, but when a user is not logged in, the query is returning my own username as being logged in. I'd simply like either no output when a user is not logged in, or just a simple "No user logged on" to appear in the output.

I've tried the WMI route with:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_LoggedOnUser -ComputerName $Comp
```

But this returns way too much output and is very difficult to filter out.

I've also tried the CIM route with:

```
(Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $Comp).UserName
```

CIM works really well and has the output that I want, but the problem is that most of the machines in my environment do not support the WS-Management protocol, and so they error out when queried.

The `Get-Process` route works the best so far, and it's fast. I just cant figure out how to filter the output to prevent showing my username for remote machines where no one is logged in locally.

```
Invoke-Command -Computername $Comp -Scriptblock {
    Get-Process -IncludeUserName | Select-Object UserName | Where-Object { $_.UserName -ne $null -and $_.UserName.StartsWith("DomainName") } | Sort-Object SessionId -Unique
}
```

When a user is logged in locally on a remote machine, their username is displayed in the output. When a user is not logged in locally on a remote machine, my username is displayed in the output.

I would like either nothing displayed, or "No user logged in" to be displayed whenever no user is logged in locally on a remote machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out the process that runs your remoting command (which runs in the context of *your* username) via its process ID, which is reflected in automatic variable `$PID` inside the remotely executing script block passed to `Invoke-Command -ComputerName`:

As an aside: The *name* of the process in which the remote command executes is `wsmprovhost`.

In the context of your command:

<sup>Note: In PSv3, use `Where-Object { $_.Id -ne $PID }` instead of `Where-Object Id -ne $PID` below.</sup>

```
Invoke-Command -Computername $Comp -Scriptblock {
  Get-Process -IncludeUserName | 
    Where-Object Id -ne $PID |
      Select-Object UserName |
        Where-Object { $_.UserName -ne $null -and $_.UserName.StartsWith("DomainName") } | 
          Sort-Object UserName -Unique
}
```

- I've changed `Sort-Object SessionId -Unique` to `Sort-Object UserName -Unique`, assuming that your intent is to list the unique usernames.
- The default output shows not just the usernames, but also the properties `.PSComputerName` and `.RunspaceId` that remoting automatically decorates the output objects with.

  - If you just want the usernames, append use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Username` instead of `Select-Object UserName`, and `Sort-Object -Unique` instead of `Sort-Object UserName -Unique`.

    - **Note**: For some processes, *no* username is reported, which is the case for the `Idle` process (are there others?). This empty username is eliminated from the output if you output the usernames only.